# Make last page of a UIScrollView inaccessible but visible in the "end-bounce"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, bounce

Was just wondering if anyone had any "simple" ideas to do this. Effectively I'd like a way of ending the scrollView on the penultimate page (subview), but have the last one visible in the bounce - though the not accessible (the scrollView won't page to that view).

I've attempted a few workarounds but not come upon anything successful as of yet.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may be able to work something out with the contentSize.  ContentSize would be as wide(or tall) as the pageable area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Set the scroll view’s content size smaller than the actual width of your content—say if you have three 320pt-wide views in it and you only want the first two accessible, set its content size to `(640, <whatever>)`. The third of the views will be visible at the end of the scroll view when it’s bouncing but otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: Thank-you, worked a charm (probably should have figured that out in hindsight!)